# UiPath Automating clicks of a list sequentially on a webpage

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

This is the [website](https://www.bursamalaysia.com/trade/trading_resources/listing_directory/main_market) I am looking at.

In this website there is a list of companies where I can click into them:

1. Click the name of the company
2. Click the "Annual Report" button
3. Click the "Annual Report & CG Report - 2018" link

There are 788 companies in this list and I wish to repeat this process for the whole list.
Is this possible?

Currently I used `Data Scraping` -> `Attach Browser url` -> `Extract Structured Data`. After that I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me that sounds pretty simple:

1. go to [overview](https://www.bursamalaysia.com/trade/trading_resources/listing_directory/main_market)
2. download the **list** via data scraping
3. for each on that **list** and surf to each of those **urls**
4. on the **url** do the things you said, like **clicking the Annual Report** and then **Annual Report & CG Report - 2018**

So the usual structure of a UiPath process is this one:

[image]

This is the Main.xaml **visual overview** that works on your example:

[image]

And this is the Main.xaml **code**:

```
<Activity mc:Ignorable="sap sap2010" x:Class="Main" mva:VisualBasic.Settings="{x:Null}" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="530,1075" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="ActivityBuilder_1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:mva="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:sap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities/presentation" xmlns:sap2010="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2010/xaml/activities/presentation" xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:sd="clr-namespace:System.Data;assembly=System.Data" xmlns:ui="http://schemas.uipath.com/workflow/activities" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <TextExpression.NamespacesForImplementation>
    <scg:List x:TypeArguments="x:String" Capacity="22">
      <x:String>System.Activities</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Activities.Statements</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Activities.Expressions</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Activities.Validation</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Activities.XamlIntegration</x:String>
      <x:String>Microsoft.VisualBasic</x:String>
      <x:String>Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities</x:String>
      <x:String>System</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Collections</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Collections.Generic</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Data</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Diagnostics</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Drawing</x:String>
      <x:String>System.IO</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Linq</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Net.Mail</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Xml</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Xml.Linq</x:String>
      <x:String>UiPath.Core</x:String>
      <x:String>UiPath.Core.Activities</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Windows.Markup</x:String>
      <x:String>UiPath.CV</x:String>
    </scg:List>
  </TextExpression.NamespacesForImplementation>
  <TextExpression.ReferencesForImplementation>
    <scg:List x:TypeArguments="AssemblyReference" Capacity="18">
      <AssemblyReference>System.Activities</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>Microsoft.VisualBasic</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>mscorlib</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Data</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Drawing</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Core</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Xml</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Xml.Linq</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>PresentationFramework</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>WindowsBase</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>PresentationCore</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Xaml</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>UiPath.System.Activities</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>UiPath.UiAutomation.Activities</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>UiPath.CV</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.ValueTuple</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Data.DataSetExtensions</AssemblyReference>
    </scg:List>
  </TextExpression.ReferencesForImplementation>
  <Sequence sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="510,975" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="Sequence_3">
    <Sequence.Variables>
      <Variable x:TypeArguments="sd:DataTable" Default="[New System.Data.DataTable]" Name="ExtractDataTable" />
      <Variable x:TypeArguments="ui:Browser" Name="Browser" />
    </Sequence.Variables>
    <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
        <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
      </scg:Dictionary>
    </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
    <ui:OpenBrowser CommunicationMethod="{x:Null}" Hidden="{x:Null}" NewSession="{x:Null}" Private="{x:Null}" BrowserType="Firefox" DisplayName="Open Browser" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="468,351" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="OpenBrowser_1" UiBrowser="[Browser]" Url="https://www.bursamalaysia.com/trade/trading_resources/listing_directory/main_market">
      <ui:OpenBrowser.Body>
        <ActivityAction x:TypeArguments="x:Object">
          <ActivityAction.Argument>
            <DelegateInArgument x:TypeArguments="x:Object" Name="ContextTarget" />
          </ActivityAction.Argument>
          <ui:BrowserScope Browser="{x:Null}" SearchScope="{x:Null}" TimeoutMS="{x:Null}" UiBrowser="{x:Null}" BrowserType="Firefox" DisplayName="Attach Browser" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="434,252" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="BrowserScope_2" InformativeScreenshot="49520eaf054f3a2d88e58aa9f0f1cdb7" Selector="&lt;html app='firefox.exe' title='Main Market' /&gt;">
            <ui:BrowserScope.Body>
              <ActivityAction x:TypeArguments="x:Object">
                <ActivityAction.Argument>
                  <DelegateInArgument x:TypeArguments="x:Object" Name="ContextTarget" />
                </ActivityAction.Argument>
                <ui:ExtractData DelayBetweenPagesMS="{x:Null}" ContinueOnError="True" DataTable="[ExtractDataTable]" DisplayName="Extract Structured Data" ExtractMetadata="&lt;extract&gt;&lt;column exact='1' name='Name' attr='text' name2='URL' attr2='href'&gt;&lt;webctrl tag='tr'/&gt;&lt;webctrl tag='td' class=' text-left position-relative'/&gt;&lt;webctrl tag='a' class='company-announcement-link' idx='1'/&gt;&lt;/column&gt;&lt;/extract&gt;" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="334,106" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="ExtractData_2" MaxNumberOfResults="100" NextLinkSelector="&lt;webctrl parentid='DataTables_Table_0_next' tag='A' /&gt;" SimulateClick="True">
                  <ui:ExtractData.Target>
                    <ui:Target ClippingRegion="{x:Null}" Element="{x:Null}" InformativeScreenshot="c9106f042e4e67a92a010ed284896366" Selector="&lt;webctrl parentid='DataTables_Table_0' tag='TBODY' /&gt;" WaitForReady="COMPLETE">
                      <ui:Target.TimeoutMS>
                        <InArgument x:TypeArguments="x:Int32" />
                      </ui:Target.TimeoutMS>
                    </ui:Target>
                  </ui:ExtractData.Target>
                </ui:ExtractData>
              </ActivityAction>
            </ui:BrowserScope.Body>
          </ui:BrowserScope>
        </ActivityAction>
      </ui:OpenBrowser.Body>
    </ui:OpenBrowser>
    <ui:ForEachRow CurrentIndex="{x:Null}" DataTable="[ExtractDataTable]" DisplayName="For Each Row" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="468,492" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="ForEachRow_1">
      <ui:ForEachRow.Body>
        <ActivityAction x:TypeArguments="sd:DataRow">
          <ActivityAction.Argument>
            <DelegateInArgument x:TypeArguments="sd:DataRow" Name="row" />
          </ActivityAction.Argument>
          <Sequence DisplayName="Body" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="376,344" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="Sequence_7">
            <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
              <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
                <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
              </scg:Dictionary>
            </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
            <ui:NavigateTo Browser="[Browser]" DisplayName="Navigate To" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="334,59" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="NavigateTo_1" Url="[&quot;https://www.bursamalaysia.com&quot; + row(&quot;Url&quot;).ToString]" />
            <Delay Duration="00:00:05" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="334,22" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="Delay_1" />
            <ui:LogMessage DisplayName="Log Message" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="334,91" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="LogMessage_3" Level="Info" Message="[&quot;Here you do all the stuff like Click Annual Report...&quot;]" />
          </Sequence>
        </ActivityAction>
      </ui:ForEachRow.Body>
    </ui:ForEachRow>
  </Sequence>
</Activity>
```

Comment: I am stuck at number 3, where I don't know how to automate to surf to each of those urls.

Comment: Just added the fully working project. Simply take the code and overwrite your Main.yaml file and restart UiPath.

Comment: Did it solve your issue? If so mark it as your solution, otherwhise ask again if you have trouble to finish your task. But SO is usually not for doing whole solutions like I did, so please make sure you tried out all you can my friend.

Comment: Hi @kwoxer before that I really want to thank you for your effort in helping. I have some problem again. I am not sure where to paste your codes above. You mentioned Main.yaml file and I am not sure what is that.

Comment: Please also upvote the answer as I put some effort in it and would be nice to get some points back. Thank you.