# Uipath-Studio, how to data scrape a list of products?

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot

[.CSV Product List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FySt.jpg)
I have a .CSV file with a list of product. And I need to make a RPA bot to Data scrape the list of products from online shopping websites. The data scraped from online shooping sites must be stored into the same DataTable. The bot must also be able to extract the product name from .CSV file and search the product's name on shopping site by itself, no matter how many items I add-on or reduce from the .CSV file in the future. I had added the picture of my .CSV product list, please ignore the Budget column. I understand how to data scrape, but I am not sure of how to design a RPA bot with such feature I mentioned above. Please help me T^T...

Comment: Sounds very easy. How far did you come? Can you share your process? Also have a look here as it seems very similar to yours. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61380604/uipath-automating-clicks-of-a-list-sequentially-on-a-webpage

Comment: At current stage, I am only able to set my RPA bot to search only 1 product from the e-commerce website and data scrape the search result. And also, store the scraped data into my DataTable Variable. I tried to let my RPA bot to extract the list of product from my .CSV product list and search and data scrape the search result. But I failed to do so. 

My current stage is Start RPA>Open Browser>Go to e-commerce website>Search for Product (Using only 1 item name)>Click search button>Data Scrape the search result>Output into a Data Table Variable

Comment: But what is the issue then? Please also share the website to be able to help you.

Comment: The website is https://www.lazada.sg/. The issue is not with the website, the issue is I do not understand how to use Uipath to search the product using a list(.CSV) of product and repeat the Data Scrape for all the search result.

Comment: Please have a look on my Answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61380604/uipath-automating-clicks-of-a-list-sequentially-on-a-webpage It's pretty much exactly the same that you need. Instead of taking the list from the website, you take it from the csv file. You can do that with the activity called `ReadCSVFile`.